# What are the expected codes and meanings for siteRefreshInfo.code?

Tags: yodlee

In issuing either a getSiteRefreshInfo or getMFAResponseForSite, what are the possible values for code?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below article on the Yodlee's dev portal for parameters

https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/getMFAResponseForSite

And

https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/getSiteRefreshInf

Also did you mean what type of error codes these APIs will return?

Comment: You misunderstood my question.  I was not asking about the parameters.  My question is about the possible values for “code.”

See this sample response.  The “code”: returns an 801 which I believe means that I should retry.  However, I’ve also seen it return a 402.  I cannot find the documentation which describes the possible values and their descriptions that will be returned in this element.

"siteRefreshInfo": {
        ...
        "code": 801,
    },

Comment: Please check this link for all the possible code which siteRefreshInfo can return.https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes

Answer (score 0):

I've learned that the getSiteRefreshInfo request may response with any of the error codes listed in https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes, so your code must account for these.  You may stop looping your web service calls when the JSON response "code" element is 0 (success) or one of the failure values listed in the link above.